# Are there any specific tips and tricks for optimizing a website for Bing?

Tags: seo, bing

Most available resources (even Bing community) promote the general principles for optimize a site in Google. My site is quite well optimized for a certain keyword combination in Google, yet in Bing it fails to even show up on 1st page. Now, I'm aware both engines do not employ same algorithm. In this case, then there should be particularities in Bing SEO, too. All I found online was pretty vague.

Comment: How have you optimized for Google? If you optimize your site for users (which is what Google recommends), then it should be optimized for all major search engines. The rankings won't be exactly the same, but the results shouldn't be as different as you're describing.

Comment: +1 for a question very relevant to my interests! I rank well on Google and Yahoo for the terms I want but not Bing.

Comment: +1 SEO stands for search engine optimization. Not Google optimization. They all work in very similar ways and everyone is essentially trying to copy Google anyway. Plus sites should be designed around users, not search engines.

Comment: @Toby, doesn't Bing power Yahoo now?

Comment: @John, if so, bugger! I am still ranked well, I wonder if or when I will drop?

Answer (score 6):

Here are a few resources that might help you:

- [Google vs. Bing: Correlation
  Analysis of Ranking Elements](http://www.seomoz.org/blog/google-vs-bing-correlation-analysis-of-ranking-elements)
- [Bing vs. Google: Prominence of
  Ranking Elements](http://www.seomoz.org/blog/bing-vs-google-prominence-of-ranking-elements)
- [Linkfromdomain - A Linkbuilding Tip
  For Use at Bing.com](http://www.seomoz.org/blog/linkfromdomain-a-linkbuilding-tip-for-use-at-bingcom)
- [Optimizing For Bing](http://www.seobook.com/optimizing-bing)
- [Bing vs. Google: 5 Real World SERPs
  Analyzed: Part 1](http://www.huomah.com/Search-Engines/Search-Engine-Optimization/Bing-vs.-Google-5-Real-World-SERPs-Analyzed-Part-1.html)
- [Google vs. Bing Part II: Link
  Analysis](http://www.huomah.com/Search-Engines/Search-Engine-Optimization/Google-vs.-Bing-Part-II-Link-Analysis.html)

Answer (score 5):

Two particular tips I've seen a few times (e.g. [here](http://everyjoe.com/work/bing-seo-tips-or-should-it-be-deo-tips/)) are:

1. **Domain age** is a big factor in Bing. Google has their sandbox (or whatever they call it) where new domains are "given the benefit of the doubt" with a small boost early and then dropped back later on. Bing doesn't have this AFAIK and new domains will take a while to gain any traction.
2. Don't be afraid to **link out**. Too many people are worried about "losing PageRank" and so refrain from linking to other sites. However if a site is completely "self-contained," that could be seen as spam I guess.

But there really is nothing concrete as far as I can tell. No sites provide any research or evidence to back claims up. Simply creating great content and gaining many in-links is key for all search engines.

(Incidentally, there is definitely a gap in the market for a site targeted to "bing seo". Search that term and just marvel at the horrendously low quality of every site that comes up. None of them appear to have any inlinks either since they are such poor quality.)

Answer (score 1):

Bing has a webmaster tools package available that they claim will help you sort out any issues.  I'm not sure if there's any difference between it and Google's webmaster tools, but I'm always skeptical of all Microsoft's claims....

http://www.bing.com/toolbox/webmasters/

Comment: Bing's webmaster tools are a poor imitation of Google's, Microsoft seem keen on providing graphs of crawl rate and indexed pages but not much else. Plus they are 100% Silverlight so don't work on Mac/Linux.

Comment: Hey, I never said they were good.....What do you expect from the maker of WindowsME?

Comment: Yeah, I'm aware Bing has a similar set of webmaster tools like Google's. I'll need to implement some authentication code if I want to take advantage of Bing's tools and I'm not sure if this code will be compatible with the already-implemented Google code... Any thoughts?