# how to do bing seo

Tags: seo, bing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are there any specific tips and tricks for optimizing a website for Bing?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/3763/are-there-any-specific-tips-and-tricks-for-optimizing-a-website-for-bing)

i have three games sites,which are all have the much better alexa around 12.000
i wanna know that if i wanna to get more traffice from bing,how to do the seo tips?is it the same with the seo in google?!thank you so much

Comment: Make an interesting site and search engines (and people) will come.

Comment: @Joachim Sauer : submitting sites to serch engines  is great way top get traffic..because my blogs never come in Bing serches..so i submitted my sites

Answer (score 0):

You can submit your sites to the Bing search engine
at http://www.bing.com/webmaster/SubmitSitePage.aspx

This helps Bing in crawling all of your pages and your site's traffic will increase!

Answer (score 0):

Sign up for google webmaster tools:

http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools

And submit your site map.

This will definitely increase your hits.

Comment: Did you even read the question?