# Ranking websites in Bing & Yahoo search engines

Tags: seo, search-engines, google-search, local-seo, google-local-search

I'm finding it extremely difficult to rank websites on Bing and Yahoo. When a website ranks well on Google, why is it finding difficulties on Yahoo and Bing? Although the algorithms are different, I have read in some blogs that its easy to rank on Bing & Yahoo compared with Google. Is that true? Am I missing something?

Comment: have you registered on Bing Webmaster Tools? BWMT has a set of tools which might help you look at potential problems (if any).

Comment: Yes, setting Google & Bing webmaster tools is the first thing I done whn started SEO.

Comment: So how are the target keywords for your site performing? You can see the performance in Search Keywords report in the Reports & Data section. If they are doing worse than what you expected, then you can always use the SEO Analyzer in the Diagnostic & Tools section to see what you can do to improve the on-page for that target keyword for that page.

Comment: Prasad... the keywords are not ranking that well on Bing. The site ranks 30th on Bing which ranks 1st on Google. Most of the targeted keywords are ranks like this. Just worried about the the huge difference in ranking between the 2 SEs. Not much onpage optimization left to do. Bing's SEO analyzer shows some missing alt tags, meta lang info which is of low priority that's it. Nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

I think the general consensus is that if you're optimized for Google, you should do fine in the others. See this previous [Question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/3763/are-there-any-specific-tips-and-tricks-for-optimizing-a-website-for-bing)

Although the discussions there are from 2010, I think most of it still holds true.

A few differences between Google and Bing are:

- Bing looks for keywords to match the content exactly, whereas Google will allow for synonyms and more contextual meanings. So you might want to examine how your keywords appear in your content.
- Google pays less attention to domain age than Bing, which places more importance on this. So if your domain is new, it may rank lower in Bing than Google.
- Bing may prioritize local results first, particularly for ambiguous search requests. So if your site is not locally based, then it may rank higher in Google.
- Google is fine with forums, but Bing isn't, so if your site is heavily centered around a forum(s), that might be one issue causing a lower ranking in Bing.

Comment: Thanks dan. the situation is the website not even shows up on bing even for the best keyword which it does on Google(for several years). Bing webmaster tool doesn't help I guess. If we forget about Google, is there any stand alone strategy to rank well on Bing?

Comment: No problem. I was still writing/editing my answer prior to your comment. Please take a look at it now.

Comment: Here's a link I have bookmarked on the subject:
http://www.stateofsearch.com/smx-advanced-london-2011-seo-for-google-vs-bing-how-different-are-they/

Comment: @dan That link is dead.

Comment: @Chloe Ah, looks like that site is down now, thanks. Here's a newer link on the subject:  http://www.searchenginejournal.com/10-ways-optimize-website-bing/120753/